# Laravel/Lighthouse, Graphql, Vue3: File Upload doesn't work

Tags: graphql, vue-apollo, laravel-lighthouse

I'm trying to upload a file in my Vue3 (Vite) project using graph-QL, Apollo and Lighthouse but **the documentation doesn't help me much**.

I followed all instructions written in the official [lighthouse upload file section](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/digging-deeper/file-uploads.html#setup) adding the scalar and the mutation.

```
scalar Upload
@scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\Upload")
```

Changed the schema so that the avatar field is of Upload type

```
type User {
id: ID!
username: String!
email: String!
password: String!
email_verified_at: Date
active: Boolean!
user_type: UserType!
avatar: Upload ...
```

And set the mutation

```
input addSupplierInput {
active: Boolean
username: String @rules(apply: ["required", "min:5", "max:20"])
email: String @rules(apply: ["required", "email", "unique:users,email"])
password: String! @hash @rules(apply: ["required", "min:2"])
active: Boolean! @rules(apply: ["required"])
user_type: String! @rules(apply: ["required"])
avatar: Upload
```

Created the Upload mutation in Laravel app/GraphQL/Mutations

```
class Upload

public function __invoke($_, array $args)
{
    $file = $args['avatar'];

    return $file->storePublicly('uploads');
}
```

When I try to upload the file through the form I get the following error in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Variable "$avatar" got invalid value "C:\fakepath\Schermata 2022-10-20 alle 12.37.53.png"; Expected type Upload; Could not get uploaded file, be sure to conform to GraphQL multipart request specification: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec Instead got: C:\fakepath\Schermata 2022-10-20 alle 12.37.53.png
```

As far I understand I've to do something of a client side [multipart file specification](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec) but I don't find any solution for Vue.js (or I don't understand what to do).

Please, any help will be appreciated. I'm simply getting crazy and I don't find any paper/video in internet that can help me .

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
I've followed this article [here](https://devpress.csdn.net/vue/62f0d3c57e6682346618346b.html), installed the **apollo-upload-client** package, updated the  **main.js** file removing the **createHttpLink** and saved the file.

main.js **BEFORE**

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  createHttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
 } from '@apollo/client/core';

 // HTTP connection to the API
 const httpLink = createHttpLink({
   uri: 'http://localhost/graphql',
 });

 // Cache implementation
 const cache = new InMemoryCache();

 // Create the apollo client
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache,
});
```

main.js **AFTER**

```
  import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core';
  import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';

  // Cache implementation
  const cache = new InMemoryCache();

  // Create the apollo client
  const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: createUploadLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost/graphql',
  }),
  cache,
});
```

I just wonder why this solution doesn't appear on the official documentation.